# Showing multi-columns

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I have 40 columns, and want my report can show 10 columns and 5 rows max per page:

```
Page1:
col1----clo2----clo3----clo4----clo5----clo6----clo7----clo8----clo9----clo10
1 ------- 1----- 1 ----- 1 ----- 1 ----- 1 ----- 1 ----- 1 ----- 1 ----- 1
2 ------- 2----- 2 ----- 2 ----- 2 ----- 2 ----- 2 ----- 2 ----- 2 ----- 2
3 ------- 3----- 3 ----- 3 ----- 3 ----- 3 ----- 3 ----- 3 ----- 3 ----- 3
4 ------- 4----- 4 ----- 4 ----- 4 ----- 4 ----- 4 ----- 4 ----- 4 ----- 4
5 ------- 5----- 5 ----- 5 ----- 5 ----- 5 ----- 5 ----- 5 ----- 5 ----- 5
Page2:
col11----clo12----clo13----clo14----clo15----clo16----clo17----clo18----clo19----clo20
1 ------- 1-------- 1 ----- 1 ------ 1 ------- 1 ------- 1 ------ 1 ------ 1 ------ 1
2 ------- 2-------- 2 ----- 2 ------ 2 ------- 2 ------- 2 ------ 2 ------ 2 ------ 2
3 ------- 3-------- 3 ----- 3 ------ 3 ------- 3 ------- 3 ------ 3 ------ 3 ------ 3
4 ------- 4-------- 4 ----- 4 ------ 4 ------- 4 ------- 4 ------ 4 ------ 4 ------ 4
5 ------- 5-------- 5 ----- 5 ------ 5 ------- 5 ------- 5 ------ 5 ------ 5 ------ 5
....

page4:
...

page5:
col1----clo2----clo3----clo4----clo5----clo6----clo7----clo8----clo9----clo10
 ------- 6----- 6 ----- 6 ----- 6 ----- 6 ----- 6 ----- 6 ----- 6 ----- 6
7 ------- 7----- 7 ----- 7 ----- 7 ----- 7 ----- 7 ----- 7 ----- 7 ----- 7
8 ------- 8----- 8 ----- 8 ----- 8 ----- 8 ----- 8 ----- 8 ----- 8 ----- 8
9 ------- 9----- 9 ----- 9 ----- 9 ----- 9 ----- 9 ----- 9 ----- 9 ----- 9
10 ----- 10---- 10 ---- 10 ---- 10 ---- 10 ---- 10 ---- 10 ---- 10 ---- 10
...
```

Could you please help me?
View detail for this question in this link: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3447865

Comment: Sorry because my post too difficult to review, you can view for example following this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wbvpmmg6pgwvel3/ForDetailMyQuestion.xlsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Use the sub reports concept.

In 1st report place 10 columns in details section and right click on details section->section expert->in paging tab->give visible records as 5.

Create another 3 sub reports with above process.

Comment: I create a group and place subreports in group fooder. But seem to be it is not work like I saw. It show all data of main report, after that, it show all data of subreport.
I want my report show like this:
dropbox.com/s/wbvpmmg6pgwvel3/ForDetailMyQuestion.xlsx

I want with 10 columns first, it will show 5 rows in page 1 and next page, it will show next 10 columns and 5 rows.

Comment: Yes, I did. I plcaed my sub-reports in Group Footer. Does it right or wrong?

Comment: Hi Just check whether your are getting the result based on your requirement or not.If not please tell what is the issue

Comment: My table have 40 columns and 20 rows:
Following your recommends, it showed following this rule: PAGE 1: col 1-10, first 5 rows. PAGE 2: col 1-10, next 5rows....PAGE 4: col 1-10, last 5 rows. PAGE 5: col 11-20, first 5 rows. PAGE 6: col 11-20, next 5 rows...PAGE 8: col last 5 rows...

But, my expectation is: PAGE 1: col 1-10, first 5 rows, PAGE 2: col 11-20: first 5 rows....PAGE 4: col 31-40, first 5 rows...Page 13: col 1-10: last 5 rows... PAGE 16: col 31-40, last 5 rows.

Could you kindly help me.

Comment: Hi what i said is 
create a sub report with 1st 10 columns.A
nd then create another sub report with next 11-20 columns.
Again create another sub reports with 21-30 columns.
Last sub report with 31-40 columns 
and then right click on details section of every sub report->section expert->in paging tab->give visible records as 5.

Comment: Can you describle where place the subreports. Detail Section a for Subreport 1. detail Section b for subreport 2.... Is it right, if not, could you kindly give me the sample.
Many thanks .

Comment: Hi Take a container report and place all the sub reports in report footer.put sub report 1 in report footer a ,put sub report 2 in report footer b.................

Comment: Hi, it is not work like I hope, althought I create a blank report, Container.rpt and puts the subreports in difference report fooders of Container.rpt like your recommended, it still shows all data of subreport 1 first, next to all data of subreport 2.

Comment: This is my sample report: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9kemqfxret5vx78/Container.rpt

Could you kindly review it for more detail

Comment: Hi Checked your report.This is also displaying 1st report then next report.The solution i suggested will display data like this only.If not tell me the problem and your exact requirement.Please

Comment: Hi, I want my report showed like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hvkq664581l0gs9/MultipleColumns.pdf

But with this, it have some problem with page footer(page number). It does not show page number at the page has Effective Time column. Do you see it?
Please give me some suggestions if you know something.
Many thanks.

Comment: Hi i dnt have access to open the link.Please tell what is the problem exactly.or please paste some images

Comment: Hi Also please go throuh the below post there you will find a sample report exactly same as your reauirement.http://scn.sap.com/message/14457658

Comment: Follow your link, the entire Report Footer second will be displayed after the entire of report footer first will be displayed.

My expectation is they will show come between each other

Comment: I want they will show come each other, the report footer second will intermix with the report footer first ?
 
Page 1: report footer 1
Page 2: report footer 2
Page 3: report footer 1
Page 4: report footer 2
...
until the entire both of them will showed.

Answer (score 0):

Place the created sub report at group level and try viewing the report.